# How can I limit a Twitter API search query to only tweets sent from the United States?

Tags: json, api, twitter

I need to search tweets sent from the United States matching a certain keyword (ex. `acme`).

Here's my search url so far:

`https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=acme&rpp=100`

But is there a way to filter out those tweets not initiated from the United States?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a direct way to restrict search by Country, instead you can use geocode which takes three parameters latitude, longitude and a radius.

Example: 
https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=acme&rpp=100&geocode=39.8,-95.583068847656,2500km

That will return tweets created in lower 48 states of US.

Here is [a link](http://thoughtfaucet.com/search-twitter-by-location/) to nice article about twitter location search.